# primefaces datatable thead same width like the tbody

Tags: html, css, jsf, primefaces, datatable

How can I force the Header to have the same width like the table?

I have special datatable with 30 Columns and the headertext is always shorter then data inside the tbody (using 45 degrees headertext).

This Configuration of the Primefaces datatable expand the table to the pagesize and all work fine but i need more space.

<--- window --->

<----- table ----->

```
<p:dataTable value="#{manager.lazyModel}"
             var="o"
             id="dataTable" 
             scrollable="true"
             liveScroll="true"
             scrollRows="150"
             scrollHeight="1000"    
             lazy="true"
             selection="#{manager.selectObj}"
             selectionMode="multiple"
             rowKey="#{o.id}"
             styleClass="mytable">
```

If i set the width of the table from 100% to auto the problem is solved for the tbody but the thead does not have the correct width (all have columns same width).

<--- window --->

<-------- table/full width ----->

```
.ui-datatable {
display: table;
}

.ui-datatable table {
table-layout: auto !important;
}
```

I cant find a solution.

Comment: That is caused by setting the layout to auto. That is just not what PF datatable requires. If you want to use auto, youhave to write a lot of custom css and jquery to get it to behave as?you want. It is almost like creating a new mode for the datatable. Not sure if you tried the latest PFversion. I doubt someone will do all this work for you

Comment: I am use version 5.2 and checked up to 5.2.10 but with no sucess. I thought someone has maybe found a workaround. The problem is the fixed header which copied as an own table.